# ansible role not executing on server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm running a ansible playbook to install a new version of ruby on a linux(ubuntu) ec2 machine.

Playbook tasks seem to be running but when i check the server nothing has changed.

```
---
- name: upgrade
  action: apt update_cache=yes upgrade=yes

- name: install ruby dependencies
  action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
  with_items:
    - build-essential
    - automake
    - bison
    - autoconf
    - pkg-config
    - libreadline6
    - libreadline6-dev
    - openssl
    - libssl-dev
    - curl
    - git-core
    - zlib1g
    - zlib1g-dev
    - libyaml-dev
    - libsqlite3-dev
    - libxml2-dev
    - libxslt1-dev
    - curl
    - libmagickwand-dev
    - imagemagick

- name: Install app dependencies
  action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
  with_items:
    - libpq-dev
    - nodejs
    - imagemagick
  tags: package
```

## from this point on, i get skipping and changed but server has not changed.

```
- name: ruby-from-src | ensure directory temporary ruby download directory is present
  file: state=directory path={{rubyTmpDir}}

- name: ruby-from-src | Download ruby source
  get_url: url={{rubyUrl}} dest={{rubyTmpDir}}

- name: ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is extracted
  command: tar -xf {{rubyCompressedFile}} chdir={{rubyTmpDir}} creates={{tmpRubyPath}}

- name: ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is configured
  command: ./configure chdir={{tmpRubyPath}} creates={{tmpRubyPath}}/Makefile

- name: ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is compiled
  command: make chdir={{tmpRubyPath}} creates={{tmpRubyPath}}/ruby

- name: ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is installed
  command: make install chdir={{tmpRubyPath}} creates=/usr/local/bin/ruby

- name: Install Bundler
  command: gem install bundler
```

What am i missing. The install ruby dependencies does just that,

output

```
TASK [webserver : Install app dependencies] *************************************************************************
ok: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com] => (item=[u'libpq-dev', u'nodejs', u'imagemagick'])

TASK [webserver : ruby-from-src | ensure directory temporary ruby download directory is present] ********************
ok: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK [webserver : ruby-from-src | Download ruby source] *************************************************************
changed: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK [webserver : ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is extracted] *********************************************************
skipping: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK [webserver : ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is configured] ********************************************************
skipping: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK [webserver : ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is compiled] **********************************************************
skipping: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK [webserver : ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is installed] *********************************************************
skipping: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]

TASK [webserver : Install Bundler] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [ec2-52-200-1-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com]
```

Comment: Can you show the log of the playbook execution?

Comment: updated with output

Answer (score 0):

> I'm running a ansible playbook to install a **new version of ruby**

This playbook will not update ruby if it's already there.
You have `creates=` flag everywhere. For example:

```
- name: ruby-from-src | ensure ruby is installed
  command: make install chdir={{tmpRubyPath}} creates=/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

This task will execute `make install` only if there's no `/usr/local/bin/ruby` file present.

And from you question I assume that you do have ruby installed. In this case playbook skips all configuration/installation tasks as expected.